# como saber cuantas palabras tiene un String en php?

Tags: php

Hola amigo tengo un pequeño ejercicio de PHP en la cual tengo que solicitar el nombre al usuario y decirle cuantas palabras tiene su nombre completo y listo.

pero no lo consifo tengo este siguiente codigo :

```
$textosolicitado = print "var nombre= prompt('cual es tu nombre');";


echo "Tu nombre tiene:";
echo str_word_count($textosolicitado);//will return the number of words in a string
```

Comment: La mejor función para esto sería `mb_strlen`  [ver aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strlen.php). Además te permite establecer el chartset, para evitar posibles errores. Le pasas tu cadena y listo. Ejemplo: `echo "Su cadena tiene ". mb_strlen($cadena) caracteres.`. En el enlace tienes más ejemplos.

Comment: Puedes realizar un split a la cadena que te mandan, y después contar las palabras que tiene su nombre completo, aquí te dejo la documentación:  http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php

Comment: Estos comentarios deberían ser respuestas

Comment: Hola amigo A.Cedano la funcion que me dices cuenta pero las letras y no las palabras?   ? Mi fuente donde vi eso:---> (en ingles)       https://coderwall.com/p/qgeuna/php-string-length-the-right-way                         $string = 'Hello';
echo strlen($string);

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18971/5frags   Hola amigo en la docs de php me sale esto = -->  
Advertencia

Esta función está OBSOLETA en PHP 5.3.0, por lo tanto, será ELIMINADA en PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `str_word_count`, disponible desde la versión 4 de PHP, y en la 5 y 7.

La función recibe como primer parametro tu `string`, como segundo un valor opcional para retornar solo el conteo de las palabras `0` o por defecto nada, `1` retorna un array con todas las palabras encontradas y su orden, y `2` que también retorna un array pero que muestra las palabras encontradas y la posición en las que se encuentra dentro del string el cual pasaste.

De esta forma:

```
php > echo str_word_count('Hello world!');
2
```

Con un valor `1` como `formato`:

```
php > print_r(str_word_count('Hello world!', 1));
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => world
)
```

Pasando `2`, está vez muestra la posición dentro de tu `string` donde comienza la segunda palabra:

```
php > print_r(str_word_count('Hello world!', 2));
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [6] => world
)
```

El tercer parámetro y también opcional es el `charlist` que puede ser usado para agregar una lista adicional de caracteres que serán usados como palabras.

Comment: Gracias Sebastian Palma me ayudastes gracias me servio la primera, pero disculpa como puedo imprimir las segundas opciones,lo siento soy nuevo en PHP

Comment: Pero disculpe es posible pasarle como parametro una variable? como yo intento?

Comment: Claro que si @gilbertoquintero, revísalo de esta forma: `$string = 'hello world'; $format = 1; $charlist = 'àáãç3'; print_r(str_word_count($string, $format, $charlist));`.